# How to deserialize Json data to private fields without public setters?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, gson

I've managed to deserialize Json data to my private variables using Jackson ObjectMapper, however, it makes use of public setters. I have also tried Gson, however I need to create a TypeAdapter which uses a switch statement (with package-private setters, which is atleast better than public setters) in its "read" method (breaking the OCP), as well as not following liskov substitution principle because it implements a TypeAdapter and its "write" function is left empty. Is there any way to deserialize in a way which does not use public setters or break lots of principles?

Sources for which may give a better understanding the implementation of my code:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gson/gson_custom_adapters.htm#

```
public class Food {

    private String name;
    private double calories;
    @JsonAlias("serving_size_g")
    private double servingSize;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getCalories() {
    return calories;
}

public void setCalories(double calories) {
    this.calories = calories;
}

public double getServingSize() {
    return servingSize;
}
}
```

And another class uses this function to create the food object:

```
private Food getFood(String foodName) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String nutritionJsonString = apiConnector.getNutritionAsStringFromAPI(foodName);
    Food food = objectMapper.readValue(nutritionJsonString, Food.class);
    return food;
}
```

The other solution that I tried using Gson:

```
public class NutritionTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Food> {
@Override
public void write(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Food food) throws IOException {

}

@Override
public Food read(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
    final Food food = new Food();

    jsonReader.beginObject();
    while(jsonReader.hasNext()){
        switch (jsonReader.nextName()){
            case "name":
                food.setName(jsonReader.nextString());
                break;
            case "calories":
                food.setCalories(jsonReader.nextDouble());
                break;
            case "serving_size_g":
                food.setServingSize(jsonReader.nextDouble());
                break;
            default:
                jsonReader.skipValue();
        }
    }

    jsonReader.endObject();

    return food;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can define constructor:

````
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            Food food = objectMapper.readValue("""
                    {  
                       "name" : "x"
                    }
                    """, Food.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    static class Food {
        @JsonCreator
        public Food(
                @JsonProperty("name")
                String name,
                @JsonProperty("calories")
                double calories,
                @JsonProperty("serving_size_g")
                double servingSize
        ) {
            // assign to fields
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Invalid type definition for type 'Food': Failed to call `setAccess()` on Field 'name' (of class `Food`) due to `java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException`, problem: Unable to make field private java.lang.String Food.name accessible

Comment: I added better example and checked that it works